# Generic type for raw JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a script that makes a request to my API and returns the response to the caller. I'm struggling to type it up.

Responses from the API always have two properties - a boolean `success` flag indicating the state of the response, and either a `data` property containing the requested data or an `errors` property containing one or more errors. My initial attempt at typing is as follows

```js
type ApiResponse<T> = {
    success: true;
    data: T
} | {
    success: false;
    errors: string[]
}
```

However, when I went to use this to retrieve an `Event`, I found a problem: the returned data doesn't match the type I pass in, due to how JSON is encoded over the wire. Here's the type for an `Event`:

```js
type Event = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    start: Date;
    end: Date;
    visibility?: {
        host: boolean,
        bands: boolean,
        public: boolean
    }
}
```

Vs a sample response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "70a1567f-5d5d-4c25-8622-f0cea9b67056",
            "name": "Test Event",
            "start": "2024-02-18T23:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2024-02-18T23:01:00.000Z",
        },
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the dates have been string encoded to make it easier to pass over the wire. I read through the JSON spec and noticed everything should be stringified except for numbers, strings, booleans, nulls, objects, and arrays.

With this in mind, I attempted to modify my `ApiResponse` so that the caller knew the values were stringified and that they would need to unpack them. However, I can't quite seem to figure out where I'm going wrong with the type mapping. Here's the latest mapping I have:

```js
type Stringified<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends number ? number : 
                      T[key] extends boolean ? boolean :
                      T[key] extends Array<unknown> ? Stringified<T[key]> :
                      T[key] extends object ? Stringified<T[key]> :
                      string
}

type ApiResponse<T> = {
    success: true;
    data: Stringified<T>
} | {
    success: false;
    errors: string[]
}
```

However, this doesn't give the expected result for `ApiResponse<Event>`. Intellisense is taking the type hinting that they are `Stringified<Date>` instead of just `string`, and the `visibility` is being treated as type `string` when it should be `Stringified<{host: boolean, bands: boolean, public: boolean}>`. I think it may be to do with the line `T[key] extends object`, but I've tried various permutations here and can't seem to find one that works (`Object`, `{}`, `Record<unknown, unknown>`)

These errors are showing when I'm trying to hydrate the strings back into proper objects like so:

```js
function hydrateEvent(rawEvent: Stringified<Event>){
    const event: Event = {
        id: rawEvent.id,
        name: rawEvent.name,
        start: new Date(rawEvent.start),
        end: new Date(rawEvent.end)
    };

    if(rawEvent.visibility){
        event.visibility = rawEvent.visibility;
    }

    return event;
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do not possible, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just a few problems with your Stringified type.

1. Doesn't affect your code *right now* but with the way it's currently written you don't actually need to handle the array case since arrays are objects.
2. You didn't handle the Date case (at all). Since a Date is an object, you effectively did `Stringified<Date>` which breaks things.
3. `visibility` is an optional property, so it can be `undefined`. It's important to note that `T | undefined` **is not assignable** to `T` (`X extends Y` is asking "is X assignable to Y?"), so you need to somehow remove that `undefined` before checking with `extends`.

```
type Stringified<T> = {
                      // remove undefined before checking with NonNullable
    [key in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[key]> extends number ? number : 
                      NonNullable<T[key]> extends boolean ? boolean :
                      NonNullable<T[key]> extends Date ? string : // Date handled
                      NonNullable<T[key]> extends Array<unknown> ? Stringified<T[key]> :
                      NonNullable<T[key]> extends object ? Stringified<T[key]> :
                      string;
}
```

That seems to solve all the problems in your `hydrateEvent` function, at least.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-d0SRgQfH3wqc+X68wW-3xurlSDqkaQiKkZQ-mu2i6AYxiQMOi6Tn+kH6EYJidHge6IToyEwRA6bpEaAr0DAYBRPQ3QIVgIhZEAA)

Comment: That's immense, thank you so much! I didn't realise `Date` came under `object` so I think that tripped me up a bit - I assumed `object` was just for any literals defined as `{foo: 'barr'}` etc :)